# Move camera background infront of object and make it transparent

Tags: python, camera

I would like to move the camera background in front of an object that is in the field of vision f the camera and make it slightly transparent. I did not find any solution for moving objects behind the camera background.

This is the background picture of the camera.
[image]

This is the object that can be seen with the camera and in the background is the picture from the previous picture.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, could you explain in a bit more detail what you mean by "camera background"?

Comment: You might be talking about adding a *Texture Coordinate* node into a *Mapping* node and setting the location to be between your scene and the camera?  This in the *Shader Editor* :: *World* (not Object) view?  (not that this works!!)